# Making bold text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've never done something in JavaScript, thus apologies if my question is very basic.

I'm trying to manipulate (making words bold, or introducing numeration structure) the description (description:"____") part in the following code of a config.js file of a gatsbyjs project.

```
module.exports = {
  siteTitle: 'Hi! I\'m Francisco!',
  siteDescription: `Create your online curriculum in just a few minutes with this starter`,
  keyWords: ['gatsbyjs', 'react', 'curriculum'],
  authorName: 'Francisco Santos',
  twitterUsername: '_franciscodf',
  githubUsername: 'santosfrancisco',
  authorAvatar: '/images/avatar.jpeg',
  authorDescription: `Developer, passionate about what I do. Always interested in how the sites were made, I started to study HTML by hobby. <br />
    In 2012 I started working as a support technician and I approached the developers.
    In 2015, I started to study C # and started to contribute with the team giving maintenance in an application in C # and .NET. <br />
    I currently work as a frontend developer and mainly work with <strong>Javascript, NodeJS e React.</strong>`,
  skills: [
    {
      name: 'HTML',
      level: 70
    },
    {
      name: 'CSS',
      level: 60
    },
    {
      name: 'Javascript',
      level: 50
    },
    {
      name: 'NodeJs',
      level: 40
    },
    {
      name: 'React',
      level: 60
    },
    {
      name: 'Git',
      level: 70
    },
    /* more skills here */
  ],
  jobs: [
    /* more jobs here */
    {
      company: "Gympass",
      begin: {
        month: 'sep',
        year: '2019'
      },
      duration: null,
      occupation: "Frontend developer",
      description: "<b>str</b> I am <b>part</b> of the bold(Corporate team), responsible for the development and maintenance of the employee management platform, giving more and more autonomy to partner +43 677 62431314companies."
  
    },  {
      company: "Lendico",
      begin: {
        month: 'apr',
        year: '2018'
      },
      duration: null,
      occupation: "Frontend developer",
      description: "I integrate the Frontend team responsible for developing and maintaining the online lending platform."
  
    }, 
  ],
```

I've already tried the basic syntax to do that usually, but since this obviously doesn't work, I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do it *within* the "description:"

Comment: Is this for nodejs console? For HTML? Where/How is this data to be displayed?

Comment: It's the config.js file of a gatsbyjs project.

Comment: So displaying via HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a solution to render strings as HTML. You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
const contentElement = document.getElementById('content')

contentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin',`<b>str</b> I am <b>part</b> of the bold(Corporate team), responsible for the development and maintenance of the employee management platform, giving more and more autonomy to partner +43 677 62431314companies.`);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

If you're using React's components, you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yourStringData }} />
```

But one thing you should keep in mind is that with this kind of DOM manipulation, your website may get [XSS attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) (somebody can inject malicious scripts into your string, after it's converted to HTML, those scripts will be executed without users' attention)

Comment: They're using Gatsby which is built upon React so you'd use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Oh, the tag was `javascript`, I thought he was looking for Javascript's solution. Let me modify my answer. @Samathingamajig

Answer (score 1):

just do a simple string replacement, if it will be rendered in html. then add the `strong` wrapped arround the word

```js
let description = 'Create your online curriculum in just a few minutes with this starter';
let boldTheseWords = ['online', 'few', 'minutes'];
boldTheseWords.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
  description = description.replace(currentValue, `<strong>${currentValue}</strong>`);
});
console.log(description);
```

Comment: There will be an issue since you aren't checking for word boundaries. Say a word was `curfews`. This would be converted into `cur<strong>few</strong>s`